# How to embed youtube video into react app

Tags: html, reactjs, youtube

I am using

`<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed?v=i_5pt4FbzTk"></iframe>`

to embed a youtube Video into my react app. But I am getting the following error:

its in german language:

[image]

do i need something like react-player for that?

Answer (score 0):

the embed URL you are creating is not correct instead try this

```
<iframe src={`https://www.youtube.com/embed/i_5pt4FbzTk`}></iframe>
```

you need to replace **watch?v=**   with  **embed/** try this it will work,
this is the simplest way to do although one can create component also.

Comment: well i did.....